# Load balancing cron jobs

Tags: load-balancing, cron, jobs

I'm trying to setup a "balanced" cron on 3 servers. Right now,  I have about 30 jobs that should run at different days/hours on my servers. Each cron job starts with a minimum memory of 1GB and a max of 2 GB. At first, I only had about 5 jobs, so there was no problem with the free memory (each server has 24 GB out of which about 4 are free + 8 GB swap). Now I'm migrating jobs from quartz to cron so I'm going to have about 25-30 jobs in the cron. Obviously, this will cause them sometimes to interfere. This could cause an OutOfMemoryError.

My question is, is there any way I could load balance the jobs between my 3 servers ( if the first one has less than 2 GB free, run on server2, and so on) ? I'm trying to avoid dividing the jobs ( put 10 in the cron of each server), I wpould like to have them all in one cron and run them on the least busy machine. Is there any known solution to this problem ?

Comment: Have you considered using a distributed work queue, like Gearman? This way you could set up a specific number of workers per server, as to not overload it.  The cron jobs would just be submitting a work request.  It'd sit in the queue until there was a worker available to run it.